# nodejs mongodb cursor problems

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have this function that I want to return the value of a mongo query but I am getting undefined values. I am attempting to read the Email address of all of the users in the users collection of my test database.

This is my code:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var connectionString = "mongodb://cannotdivulge.info.com:53778/testdb";
var users;
var db = mongo.connect(connectionString, function(err, db) {
    if(err)
        throw err;
    console.log("connected to database");
    users = db.collection('users');
});

exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
    var cursor = users.find();
    var result;
    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
        if(err)
            throw err;
        result = doc.Email;
    });
    res.send(result);
};
```

result should be equal to the email address but it's undefined. The value of doc.Email is not being preserved. When I place res.send() inside cursor.each(), it will return a value.

Also, I will need to use the result variable in the function before actually returning it's value. That is why I need it's value to be preserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `findall` function is async. You'll need to return the results only after completing the list. In your code, the function was returning the value of `result` before the first callback for `each` had started.

```
exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
    var cursor = users.find();
    var result = [];
    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
        if(err)
            throw err;
        if (doc === null) {
            // doc is null when the last document has been processed
            res.send(result);
            return;
        }
        // do something with each doc, like push Email into a results array
        result.push(doc.Email);
    });
};
```

Comment: Correct. And if you're going to to grab a bunch of documents, place them in an array and send back to the client, you might consider using `cursor.toArray(function(err, docs){})` which takes a callback for the whole result set. See [cursor.toArray](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html#toarray)

Comment: @WiredPrairie But what if I want to use the result variable in another query before I return the value of the function? Like say I get the email and I want to check it against another collection? I need to use that variable again before returning it. That's why I need the value to not be undefined.

Comment: Wait till you get the result back, then do the next step? You're asking a new question it would seem?

Comment: @martingreber - yes, sure you can use `toArray` in some situations. It just automates a very simple loop using the same basic technique internally to an array. It presumes you've got enough RAM/memory to hold the array structure.

Comment: @WiredPrairie - I wasn't asking a new question, I guess I just didn't mention it initially but I edited my question. In any case, thanks for enlightening me with your answer. What I was trying to do is check that the users email was correct so that I could then use it (if the email is correct) to query the data collection where data is based on the users email.